# When is floor function homogeneous?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to figure out, when is $\lfloor ax \rfloor = a\lfloor x \rfloor$ for $x,a \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is floor function, and I'm completely stuck.

Is there a general rule, for which pairs of $a$ and $x$ is the equation above true? It's obvious that $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ but I couldn't get any further than that. Clearly, for fixed $a={b\over c}$ we have at least one $x$, namely $x=c$ and every multiple of $c$. But how to  find all such $a$ and $x$?

Comment: if $x = x_1 + x_2$, such that $[x] = x_1$, (i.e. $x_2$ represents the part after the decimal point) and if $ax_2 < 1$ then $[ax] = a[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that if $a \lfloor x \rfloor \notin \Bbb{Z}$, then $\lfloor ax \rfloor \in \Bbb{Z}$ so it can't be equal. Now let's suppose that $a \lfloor x \rfloor \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Now let's mark $r = x \mod 1$. Then $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + r$. And we have:$$
\lfloor ax \rfloor = a \lfloor x \rfloor\\
\lfloor a\lfloor x\rfloor + ar \rfloor = a \lfloor x \rfloor
$$
And because $a\lfloor x\rfloor\in\Bbb{Z}$:$$
a\lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor ar \rfloor = a \lfloor x \rfloor\\
\lfloor ar \rfloor = 0
$$
And this holds only for $ar \in [0;1)$.

Comment: Why is $a\lfloor x\rfloor\not\in\mathbb{Z}$?  What if $a=0.5$, and $x=2.1$, for instance.

Comment: I forgot this case. It should still hold for $a \notin \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: I corrected my answer, actually, not much has changed.